# Вывести на экран числа

Tags: c#

При помощи цикла вывести числа след образом

1
6
2   2
7   7
3   3   3
8   8   8
4   4   4   4
9   9   9   9

Comment: Ваши потуги неплохо бы увидеть

Comment: @Андрей да я циклы прописал, а дальше не смог :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например так:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 4; ++x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
        Console.Write(x + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
        Console.Write(x + 5 + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Или так:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 4; ++x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", new int[x].Select(v => x)));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", new int[x].Select(v => x + 5)));
}
```